# Crash When Reordering Items in a ListView (Windows Store App using XAML)

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, observablecollection

I have an app that uses nested list views bound to ObservableCollections. The parent list views are used for grouping items, and each group contains a ListView of items. I used ListViews and ObservableCollections because I wanted users to be able reorder the groups, and also reorder the items within the group. I do not need them to move items between groups, though I may try that later. (:

The problem is after you reorder a group, if you try and drag an item out of the re-ordered group onto another group the app will crash in Windows.UI.XML.dll, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to prevent it. I don't want people to do that, but I also need it to not crash if they try.

I was able to reproduce this using a very lightweight app.

This is the class with the ObservableCollections:

```
public class GroupList
{
    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public GroupList()
    {
        Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>();

        Group group1 = new Group("Group 1");
        group1.Items.Add(new Item("Item 1"));
        group1.Items.Add(new Item("Item 2"));
        group1.Items.Add(new Item("Item 3"));
        Groups.Add(group1);

        Group group2 = new Group("Group 2");
        group2.Items.Add(new Item("Item 4"));
        group2.Items.Add(new Item("Item 5"));
        group2.Items.Add(new Item("Item 6"));
        Groups.Add(group2);

        Group group3 = new Group("Group 3");
        group3.Items.Add(new Item("Item 7"));
        group3.Items.Add(new Item("Item 8"));
        group3.Items.Add(new Item("Item 9"));
        Groups.Add(group3);
    }
}

public class Group
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Group(string groupName)
    {
        this.GroupName = groupName;
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = null;
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public Item(string itemName)
    {
        this.ItemName = itemName;
    }
}
```

This is the XAML for the page:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <ListView Name="groupListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" IsSwipeEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ListView Name="itemListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" IsSwipeEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And this is the code-behind for the page:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private GroupList groupList = new GroupList();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        groupListView.DataContext = groupList.Groups;
    }
}
```

To reproduce this issue:
 1. Run the app
 2. Drag and drop Group 1 between Group 2 and Group 3

 3. Drag Item 1 from Group 1 onto Group 2

You should see a crash.

I have been pulling my hair out for hours trying different methods to prevent this from happening. The closest I came was handling the Drop event and setting Handled=true, but it would then still crash if you dropped it onto one of the group headers. If anyone can help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you,

Todd

Comment: Please run it in the debugger and post what Exception is being thrown. You may need to run it with the Mixed debugger, in case it's a Native exception.

Comment: The exception is a NullReferenceException ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.")

Comment: It looks like the NullReferenceException is coming from GetDraggedItems in Windows.UI.XAML.ni.dll DirectUI::ListViewBase.GetDraggedItems.